# How to get python to display the first letter from input

Tags: python, letters-and-numbers

For example, if I entered `"Harry Potter"` into the following code. What should I write in the blank spaces so that `First_letter` will be assigned with `H`, `Second_letter` with `a`, etc.

If possible, please also explain how the code works.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
Name = input("Enter your name")

First_letter = ____
Second_letter = ____
Third_letter = ____
```

Comment: Did you try doing this?

Comment: Do you have code to display _any_ letters from input? You should probably start from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution for beginners to understand in my opinion is using [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) like:

```
>>> name = list(input("Enter your name"))
>>> name
['n', 'a', 'm', 'e']
>>> First_letter = name[0]
>>> Second_letter = name[1]
>>> Third_letter = name[2]
```

Comment: you don't need to convert `str` to `list`. You could do the same with `str`

Comment: I know, but I figured he wanted to actually have characters, and also I believe it's better practice to show him  this.

Comment: That's not better practice. The call to `list` makes it overly complicated.

Comment: I don't disagree that just using the index is less complicated, But I do think that in the future, should he switch to Java/C# or basically any other language, performing such manipulations on Strings might not be possible and could cause harm. This answer is my opinion of how I would do it. It is obviously not the only answer, though it is correct nonetheless.

Comment: Unless you specifically require a list, there's no need to convert string to it, because you can use indices, slices and `for` loop over strings the same way as if it were a list. Basically, treat string as yet another sequence type in Python. And just because some other language lacks such features, it is not an excuse to dismiss them in Python. Whatever language you use, you should do things in the idiomatic way of that particular language.

Answer (score 1):

You could use index for `str` objects:

```
Name = input("Enter your name")

First_letter = Name[0]
Second_letter = Name[1]
Third_letter = Name[2]
```